# Not able to install Netlink Protocol Library Suite (libnl3)?

Tags: linux, libraries, api

I was trying to install newer version of Aircrack-ng so I downloaded it from the official site and tried to install it, but it gave the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
common.mak:120: *** Cannot find development files for any supported version of libnl. install either libnl1 or libnl3..  Stop.
```

After this I installed 
libnl-3-200
libnl-3-200-dbg
libnl-3-200-udeb
 libnl-3-dev
 libnl-cli-3-200
 libnl-cli-3-dev
 libnl-genl-3-200
 libnl-genl-3-200-udeb
 libnl-genl-3-dev
 libnl-idiag-3-200
 libnl-idiag-3-dev
 libnl-nf-3-200
 libnl-nf-3-dev
  libnl-route-3-200
 libnl-route-3-dev
 Package libnlopt-dev
 libnlopt-guile0
 libnlopt0
 ntrack-module-libnl-0
After installing all these error is still same as. Any solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to install `pkg-config`.